# Как организовать di для вызова usecase из Interceptor-а

Tags: android, архитектура

Всем привет, у меня проект на чистой архитектуре и появилась задача разлогинивания пользования и выклидывания на экран входа в случае, если в ответ на запрос приходит 401.

Разлогинивание релизовано отдельным UseCase, который должен быть вызван из интерактора.

Из-за этого появляется проблема циклической зависимости: Interceptor -> UseCase -> Repository -> Retrofit -> Okhttp -> Interceptor.

Может, есть у кого мысли как сделать не костыльное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно ли вам необходимо отправлять запрос подписанный устаревшим токеном после того, как пользователь получил ошибку 401? Мне этот момент кажется странным.

Один из стандартных подходов заключается в том, что вы используете разные объекты для доступа к авторизованной и не авторизованным зонам. В таком случае, вы можете сделать необходимый запрос, используя объект не авторизованной зоны и отправить пользователя на экран логина (локально). По ссылке вы можете ознакомиться с деталями: https://github.com/AndroidArchitecture/AndroidArchitectureBook/blob/master/cases/auth/Auth_article.md

Случай, в котором устаревший токен нужно обновить без взаимодействия с пользователем также описывается в примере.